# Cannot find the "getUriForFile" method in FileProvider

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a FileProvider to allow me to share local, private images with email and other apps. I have been following the instructions of the Android Developers Guide and get down to where I have to use the "getUriForFile" function and Eclipse tells me I have to create the method. I was under the impression this should be in the android.support.v4.content package and it is in the Referenced Libraries for the app, but it is not there.

I have added the following to my Manifest:

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.gelbintergalactic.fileprovider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
android:resource="@xml/my_paths" />
</provider>
```

I have created this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

But when I get to this point in my code I am stymied:

```
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(this, "com.gelbintergalactic.fileprovider", newfile);
```

What step am I missing?

Comment: When I tried to use the app with the manifest and xml paths file in place but with the runtime code eliminated, I got the following in LogCat: 11-12 11:57:39.357: E/AndroidRuntime(11019): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.FileProvider

Comment: I found the apparent source code for FileProvider and was able to add it to my app's code and get it to work, but it is still a mystery to me as to why this does not seem to be in the android.support.v4.content package I have linked in with Eclipse.

Comment: I now know the correct way to get the current android.support.v4 library into my app. Right-click the package, Android Tools, Add Support Library...

Answer (score 16):

Yes, instructions in dev guide are not the greatest. `getUriForFile()` is a static method of the FileProvider class so you need to do:

```
Uri contentUri =
  FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.gelbintergalactic.fileprovider", newfile);
```